# Launching Android Widget List from activity

Tags: widget, classname

Is there any way to launch the android widgets list from activity? Some like on sample code:

```
        Preference button = (Preference)findPreference("button");
        button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 

              Intent myIntent = new Intent();
              myIntent.setClassName(packageName, className);
              startActivity(myIntent);

              return true;
              }
    });
```

or another way to access the list of widgets?